# How to set up a docker-compose and Dockerfile to deploy a Laravel app?

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile, laravel-9

I recently finished developing a Laravel 9 app, using wsl2 and sail, just like I was told in the Laravel documentation. Since it’s my first time deploying to live ever, I ran into some differences with local and production files such as .env, docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile.
I tried using guides and tutorials but I can’t seem to make sense as to how to make it work. I have a droplet with a non-root user with sudo privileges, since I used these two kind guides:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-20-04
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-compose-on-ubuntu-20-04

after finishing with the installation, I tried to clone my app and run it like I do locally, and nothing happened. I realize I can’t use sail on the server, but what is the correct way to make it work?

All three local files (.env, docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile) were never edited.

Comment: I've the same problem. Do you found the correct way to deploy with docker ?

Answer (score -1):

use this repository [docker-laravel](https://github.com/amirdaraby/docker-laravel)

i have Php, Composer, and mariadb on it.